# Extract specific data from a php string

Tags: php

I have a url stored in a database in the following format

```
index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_11&products_id=568
```

I want to be able to extract the cPath data, 1_11 in this case, and the products id '568' to two separate variables. Note that the cPath value could vary from being a single number such as 23 to a series of numbers and underscores such as 17_25_31. If extracting the cPath is too difficult I could use the products_id once it's extracted and query the database again, but this isn't ideal as I want to avoid additional requests as much as possible.

I really don't know the best (correct) way to go about this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more refined approach as suggested by Robbie Averill

```
//first lets the the query string alone
$string=parse_url('index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_11&products_id=568', PHP_URL_QUERY);

parse_str($string,$moo);

print_r($moo);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [main_page] => product_info
    [cPath] => 1_11
    [products_id] => 568
)
```

My original suggestion.

```
parse_str('index.php?main_page=product_info&cPath=1_11&products_id=568',$moo);

print_r($moo);
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [index_php?main_page] => product_info
    [cPath] => 1_11
    [products_id] => 568
)
```

Comment: Better would probably be to `parse_url` first then just `parse_str` on the query string

Comment: i thought about that, but he only wanted `cPath` and `products_id` so i thought lets make it real simple. But i will add that to the answer ;-)

Comment: Works beautifully, thank you. Was easily able to assign the values to variables as $cPath = ($moo['cPath']);
$products_id = ($moo['products_id']);

Comment: @StevePrice why reassign at all? your just doubling memory usage for no advantage

Comment: @Dagon Valid point. I changed my code to access it directly after your comment.